# Flask: Localhost References When Moving from Local Machine to Production Server

Tags: python, flask, webserver, localhost

I'm about to finish my first Flask app and about to move it to a webserver and I was wondering what should I be careful with. I'm especially worried with the use of localhost references inside my app. My app has a lot of references to http:// 127.0.0.1 Port:5000. I'm very new to this and I'm wondering if I need to change any of those references when moving to a webserver? If so, what are those changes?

I have been trying to Google this but I haven't find a -dummies- version that explains it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: since you're just getting started on flask, you also might want to think about environment variables to store production/development machine specific configurations (database uris, upload folder paths, testing configuration etc...) instead of hardcoding them. A simple cookiecutter template like https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone/tree/master/fbone could give you some ideas/inspiration !

Comment: @sarul Awesome! This is very a very helpful boilerplate. I'm almost done with this app, but I'm definitely starting from this for my next one! Thanks!

Comment: glad i could help. Just do a search for flask cookie cutter and there are plenty more.

Answer (score 2):

You should not hard-code urls to your routes anywhere in your application.  Use [`url_for`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.url_for) to generate urls based on endpoint names and arguments.  Use `_external=True` to make the generated url absolute (include the domain).